# How to prove this inequality?It's hard for me.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, permutation-cycles

My classmate told me this problem yesterday.
The problem is that:
let $a,b,c,d>0$,
prove that: $\sum_{cyc}{\frac{c}{a+2b}}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{c+2d}{a}\geq8(\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}-1)$

I tried to expand it and used Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality,then I got the following result:
$$
\begin{aligned}\sum_{cyc}{\frac{c}{a+2b}}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{c+2d}{a}&={\frac{c}{a+2b}}+{\frac{d}{b+2c}}+{\frac{a}{c+2d}}+{\frac{b}{d+2a}}+\frac{c+2d}{a}+\frac{d+2a}{b}+\frac{a+2b}{c}+\frac{b+2c}{d}\\&\geq\frac{[4(a+b+c+d)]^2}{4(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)}\\&=4(\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd})\end{aligned}
$$
BUT this doesn't look right.

Comment: Can you be explicit with your CS, especially taking the equality case into consideration?

Comment: Note: OP [posted this again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948647/how-to-solve-this-inequality-help-me) a day ago, and it was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your inequality can be rearranged to
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+2b+ c}{a+2b}+\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+2b+ c}{c} &=& \sum_{cyc}{\frac{(a+2b+ c)^2}{(a+2b)c}}  \\ & \geq & 8\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}
\end{eqnarray*}
Note also that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{cyc}(a+2b)c  =2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd).
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply through by this & now apply CS.